# Is there a way I can check detect a repeated input for a hashset (Java)?

Tags: java, hashset

I am trying to make a hangman game as follows:

```
 public void guessLetter(String letter) {
    HashSet<String> guessedLettersA = new HashSet<>();
    guessedLettersA.add(letter);

    for (String guessedLetterA : guessedLettersA) {
        this.guessedLetters += guessedLetterA;
    }

    if (!this.word.contains(letter)) {
        this.numberOfFaults++;
    }
}

public boolean letterCheck() {
    if ( = false ) {
        System.out.println("You have already guessed this letter!");
    }
```

I am currently working in the letterCheck method and want to see if one of the inputs is a repeat and let the user know that their guess doesn't count. I assume it wont make up their failures or count as another guess because it is never added to the hashset. So where I am struggling with, is how do I do as I want, I was thinking of using the built-in way a hashset returns false to detect this, but I have no idea how to implement this since it needs to refer to another method and I don't know how to make a string hashset return booleans. I would greatly appreciate any help at all, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `add` API would return `false` for an existing value(that it cannot add to the `Set`), so your condition can be dealt with

```
boolean letterCheck = guessedLettersA.add(letter);
if(!letterCheck) {
    System.out.println("You have already guessed this letter!");
}
```

*Note*: The invocation of this block is solely dependent on the design of your application.